# How to call ASMX webservice from MVC view?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

Following are the  WebService method i am trying to consume-:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

using ajax call for calling this method

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebServices/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = msg.d;
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }
});
```

But everytime i am getting error of resource not found might be because i am calling it from MVC view, i also tried to put whole localhost path http://localhost:60005/ still got the error of resource not found, could someone give me a small example of calling asmx webservice from MVC view?

Comment: try calling an action method from view , and then from the controller action call your web method

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's coming from an MVC View or a Web Forms page or even a plain HTML page. It's all just HTML and JavaScript once it gets to the client. Just make sure your path is correct on the client side.

Comment: Make sure that the webservice is actually running when you are calling it. In Visual Studio there is an option "Multiple startup projects", available through Solution (right-click) -> Set StartUp Projects... -> Multiple startup projects. Set Action = Start for your WebService project + your WebApplication project.

Answer (score 2):

Try with adding this line to your RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

also, uncomment this line in your asmx web service class:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

you have a nice tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-call-webserviceasmx-from-mvc-view-using-jquery):